# ERROR: literal carriage return found in data while importing .sql file to postgres table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to import a sql script file to the Postgres table. The dump file is made using version 11.3 while my Postgres version is 14.

The command I am using `psql -U USERNAME -d DB_NAME -f FILE_NAME.sql`

ERROR I get ->

```
ERROR: literal carriage return found in data 
HINT:  Use "\r" to represent carriage return.
```

A small example of the SQL script

```
COPY public.instagram_followers (account_username, follower_username) FROM stdin;
23_is_leland    cwalkermsu20
23_is_leland    1st_brownsugar
23_is_leland    hoesluvzay_
23_is_leland    scorpiolovee__
\.
```

I have seen a couple of solutions posted on the internet but cannot figure out how to solve the issue.

This is what the official documentation says -

> Backslash characters can be used in the COPY data to quote data characters that might otherwise be taken as row or column delimiters. In particular, the following characters must be preceded by a backslash if they appear as part of a column value: backslash itself, newline, carriage return, and the current delimiter character.

> \r  Carriage return (ASCII 13)

Can someone explain this and how I should fix the error?

Comment: you need options that fit your data see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html

Comment: If you are restoring to Postgres 14, you should use the 14 version of pg_dump to dump the data from the Postgres 11.3 instance. `pg_dump` is backwards compatible not forward compatible. You should also check the settings for `backslash_quote` and `standard_conforming_strings` in the `postgresql.conf` for both Postgres instances.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL looks at the (assumed) line terminator of the (assumed) first line, and then expects that terminator for every other line.  Apparently your file inconsistently uses \r and \n, which causes confusion.  It is expecting either \n or \r\n (I don't know which), so when it finds an \r or an \r not followed by \n, it assumes it is a literal character.  Fix your file to use consistent line endings.

Comment: Yes, there were 5 rows that ended with \r. I had to Cntrl F \r to find and delete those rows. Thank you.